# Dynamically Creating a Form and Submitting With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a form object in code and populate it with data from input elements on my page. I know I can submit an existing form with ajax, but I don't want to do that. I simply want this submit to pull the information from 4 fields within the form and submit only those.

```
// Create Upload Object & Get Data
var form = document.createElement('form');
var uploadData = new FormData(form);    
uploadData.append('file[]', $("#pageUpload").files);
uploadData.append('pageItem', $("#pageItem").val());
uploadData.append('pageItem2', $("#pageItem2").val());
uploadData.append('pageItem3', $("#pageItem3").val());
```

I am assuming the issue has to do with how I am creating my upload data above, but I have also included my ajax submit code below.

```
// Create A New Ajax Request
$.ajax({
    url: './index.php?path=upload',
    data: uploadData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        processUploads(result.);
    }
});
```

Looping through the form data object I can see that does contain the key / values I have defined, but the result is always "nothing uploaded." Thanks in advance for any help with my code.

Comment: What error are you getting in the console.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I am just getting logging "nothing uploaded" also I just noticed the "." after result in the processUploads function call is a typo that is not in my actual code.

Comment: Try to figure out why that is happening, maybe your url in the xhr is wrong... I see contentType is false, why? Added in the right contentType for it in a string format, and add dataType as what you want to upload.

Comment: Sorry an important point I should have noted is that "Nothing Uploaded" is my php code response for an empty $_FILES['file'] variable.

Comment: I have it set to false because as I understand it that allows jquery to determine the type automatically.

Comment: From what I can deduce uploadData is never getting passed to the php script. Both the $_POST and $_FILES variables are empty arrays. In addition I tried to upload a HUGE file just to try and get a delay in the server's response, but I don't get one. This leads me to believe none of the data from the input fields is ever being sent tot he server.

Comment: Can you try `uploadData.append('file[]', $("#pageUpload")[0].files);`?

Comment: Same result. I have also tried omitting the file line, but still nothing posts to $_POST. Would the fact these forms are already inside a different form element defined in the HTML keep them from submitting as part of my new form?

Comment: Can you edit your post with your html?

Comment: Well I was finally able to figure it out. Apparently you can not add the entire $element.files array, but instead need to loop through the array and append each file separately. So uploadData.append('file[]', $("#pageUpload").files[i]);

Comment: processUploads(result.); //needs the dot. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was finally able to figure it out. Apparently you can not add the entire $element.files array, but instead need to loop through the array and append each file separately. So the code is

```
for(var fileIndex in $("#pageUpload")[0].files){
    uploadData.append('file[]', $("#pageUpload")[0].files[fileIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i have understand you want to send data to server via ajax request.Check the code below.

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'path/to/file',
           data: $('#formName').serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
           },
           error: function () {
                  console.log("Failed");
           }
      });
```